# How to set custom headers with a $resource POST action?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, custom-headers

headers for $resource is available since AngularJS

The format is

```js
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'something': 'anything' }
    }
});
```

Above is working for Get Method but i would like to set custom header with $resource POST method

Comment: If you want the same headers to set into every HTTP request, then [httpinterceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441042/how-to-add-new-headers-to-the-http-request-in-angularjs-through-interceptors) is the best place.

Comment: What research have you done and what problems are you having?